# Python Numpy.loadtxt with varied string entries but know line format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Busy looking into the limits of loadtxt specifically. I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
# Sample header for python loadtxt
Very random text:¤mixed with¤strings¤numbers
300057¤9989¤34956¤1
110087¤9189¤24466¤4
# EOF
```

I can read this all in as a string (unknown length) and then convert to integers and floats later. This I have here:

```
import numpy as np
txtdata = np.loadtxt('Mytxtfile.txt',delimiter=chr(164),comments="#",dtype='str')
```

However I would like to know if it is possible to extract, directly into a multidimensional array. Such as:

```
>>> 
[['Very random text:','mixed with','strings','numbers']
 [300057,9989,34956,1]
 [110087, 9189, 24466, 4]]
```

I tried this dtype command with no success:

```
dtype=[('a', 'str'),('b','int'),('c','int')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txtdata = np.loadtxt(
    'Mytxtfile.txt', delimiter=chr(164), comments="#", skiprows=1,
    dtype=[('a', '|S6'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')])
```

Your sample data shows 4 columns, so to specify the `dtype` explicitly, you would need something like:

```
dtype=[('a', '|S6'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')]
```

Note that NumPy does not have a variable-width `'str'` dtype. You have to specify the number of bytes in advance. For example, `'|S6'` specifies a 6-byte string dtype.

If you do not know in advance how many bytes may be in the string column(s), then it may be more convenient to use [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt):

```
txtdata = np.genfromtxt('Mytxtfile.txt', delimiter=chr(164), comments="#",
                        names=True, dtype=None)
```

`dtype=None` tells `genfromtxt` to make an intelligent guess for the dtype.