# Accessing a file path saved in a .txt file. (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, text, filepath

I have a text file that contains file paths of files that I wish to open.

The text file looks like this:

```
28.2 -1.0 46 14 10 .\temp_109.17621\voltage_28.200\power_-1.txt
28.2 -2.0 46 16 10 .\temp_109.17621\voltage_28.200\power_-2.txt
```

...

I would like to open the files at this filepath.

First step is to load each filepath from the text file.

I've tried this using:

```
path = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[5],dtype='S16')
```

which generates a `path[1]` that looks like:

`.\\temp_109.17621`
...

rather than the entire file path.

Am I using the wrong `dtype` or is this not possible with `loadtxt`?

Comment: loadtxt loads literally what the file contains. It does not understand that the column is a file path.

Comment: @8765674 all is correct, you use S16 as a type and was returned string with length=16 (\\ is one char). According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121949/python-numpy-loadtxt-with-varied-string-entries-but-know-line-format) try to use `np.genfromtxt` and `dtype=None` or properly adjust string length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use S16 as a type and get `.\\temp_109.17621` as an result (`\\` is escaped `\`) and was returned string with length=16.

Try to use `np.genfromtxt` and `dtype=None` or properly adjust `dtype='S45'` (in your case)

Inspired by [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121949/python-numpy-loadtxt-with-varied-string-entries-but-know-line-format)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the data type to `np.str_` it will work:

```
path = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[5],dtype=np.str_)

print(path[1])
.\temp_109.17621\voltage_28.200\power_-2.txt
```

Or using `dtype=("S44")` will also work which is the length of your longest of the two paths.
You are specifying a *16 character string* so you only get the *first 16 characters*.

```
In [17]: s = ".\\temp_109.17621"

In [18]: len(s)
Out[18]: 16

# 43 character string
In [26]: path = np.loadtxt('words.txt',usecols=[5],dtype=("S43"))    
In [27]: path[1]
Out[27]: '.\\temp_109.17621\\voltage_28.200\\power_-2.tx'    
In [28]: len(path[1])
Out[28]: 43    
# 38 character string
In [29]: path = np.loadtxt('words.txt',usecols=[5],dtype=("S38"))    
In [30]: path[1]
Out[30]: '.\\temp_109.17621\\voltage_28.200\\power_'    
In [31]: len(path[1])
Out[31]: 38
In [32]: path = np.loadtxt('words.txt',usecols=[5],dtype=np.str_)
In [33]: path[1]
Out[33]: '.\\temp_109.17621\\voltage_28.200\\power_-2.txt'
```

If you look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) you will see what every dtype does and how to use them.

If you just want all the file paths you can also use `csv.reader`:

```
import csv
with open("NonLorentzianData.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        with open(row[-1]) as f:
            .....
```

Comment: not a case as path was loaded from file, according to `.\\temp_109.17621 ...` slashes were pretty fine escaped